# How one could customize VSCode "tool/menu bar"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

## Shortly

How to add custom buttons for commands in `VSCode`?

## Detailed

It's been a while since many users of `VSCode`/`VSCodium` wanted to have something like a *common toolbar* (for example, see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41309) being in top-10 most commented issues). The most recent and usable solution I've found so far is this [Shortcut Menu Bar extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar). But it lacks some custom options like the number of seen icons, positioning, etc.

Also, [Commands extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands) addresses similar problem and provides solution with help of `Activity Bar` and/or `Status bar` but it's not a *classic toolbar* I'm looking for.

The official `VSCode` docs [lists a number of menus](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) which can be contributed by a extension writers, but I genuinely can't comprehend what menu corresponds to [this area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3axs.jpg) of `VSCode`.

Comment: The editor title menu bar - `editor/title` or editor title context menu - `editor/title/context`

Comment: @rioV8 I struggle to find these components in VSCode sources or .zip-version. Are there any settings of it in VSCode?

Comment: these are the menu's you have to set/modify in the `properties.json` of your extension

Comment: @rioV8 Do you know where I can find actual properties of these menus?